# Is it possible to pass a concept as a template parameter?

Tags: c++, c++-concepts

Is it possible to pass a concept as a template parameter? For example:

I want to do something like this:

```
template <typename t, typename u> concept range_of =
    range<t> &&
    requires (t a) {
        {*a.begin()} -> std::same_as<u &>;
    };
```

But instead of giving the exact type `u` I want to give it a concept:

```
template <typename t, {{concept u}}> concept constrained_range =
    range<t> &&
    requires (t a) {
        {*a.begin()} -> u;
    };
```

Comment: I think not, also it feels that it could lead to re-emergence of Russell's paradox :P

Comment: You cannot pass a concept, but you can pass a template whose template parameter are constrained or a struct with a member function template that constrain the argument type.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It's possible to cheat a bit since we can pass lambda functions as template arguments ; a concept is just a meta-function from the domain of types to the boolean domain after all.

Here is an example:

```
template<auto F, typename T>
using check = std::conditional_t<
      F.template operator()<T>()
    , std::true_type
    , std::false_type>;

#define CONCEPT(TheConcept) \
  [] <typename T> () consteval { return TheConcept<T>; }

static_assert(check<CONCEPT(std::floating_point), float>::value);
```

Demo on Godbolt: https://gcc.godbolt.org/z/fGf45nqTc

Comment: That's a nice trick. I'll accept this as the answer, because it doesn't require using a struct instead of a concept.

Answer (score 1):

Currently it's not possible to pass a concept as a template parameter, but you can get around it by passing a `template template`:

```cpp
#include <optional>

template <typename T>
concept Optional = requires {
  typename T::value_type;
  // ...
};


template <template<typename> typename Q, typename T>
concept OptionalOf = Optional<T> && Q<typename T::value_type>::value;
```

which you can use like this ([on compiler-explorer](https://godbolt.org/z/e9xTne)):

```cpp
constexpr bool is_optional_of_int = OptionalOf<std::is_integral, std::optional<int>>;
```

or this:

```cpp
template <typename T>
struct constrained_range {
  static constexpr bool value = range<T> && requires (T a) {
        {*a.begin()} -> u;
    };
};

constexpr bool is_optional_of_constrained_range = OptionalOf<constrained_range, std::optional<int>>;
```