# Concept to assert an argument is another concept, with whatever parameters

Tags: c++, templates, c++20, c++-concepts

Ideally, given something like this:

```
template <typename A, typename B, typename C>
concept A = ...

template <typename T, concept SomeConcept>
concept AssertAnotherConcept = ...
```

I would like to do something like this:

```
template <AssertAnotherConcept<A> TA>
class SomeClass {}
```

The problem is, it's impossible to pass a concept to another concept (although [you can cheat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63098070/is-it-possible-to-pass-a-concept-as-a-template-parameter) about it a little, but I still feel a bit uneasy) and even so, I need to do the actual assertion (probably something like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17390605/doing-a-static-assert-that-a-template-type-is-another-template)).

Is there a more built-in way to do this? What is the cleanest way?

Comment: Please make sure to read tag descriptions before adding them to a post.

Comment: How does `AssertAnotherConcept` use `SomeConcept`?